# Can I publish my model to Acumos marketplace?

Tags: acumos

My colleague used to be able to publish a ML model to Acumos marketplace and now it seems closed. I wonder when this would be open again? Also if I understand correctly Acumos only supports Tensorflow for now -- do you have any plan to support more frameworks, such as Caffe, MXNet, etc.

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 1):

The Acumos developer challenge allowed on-boarding of models, but the site https://marketplace.acumos.org does not allow on-boarding. I'll ask about plans towards re-opening that.

Acumos supports TensorFlow yes, but also Sci-Kit learn and many other modeling technologies. I recommend starting with Python-based models.

For the second release (called "Boreas") there are many open discussions about supporting interchange formats such as ONNX. If you are interested in helping the project towards that goal I recommend joining the community and contributing code!

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! Great to hear that interoperability might be supported in the next release. Will be cool if on-boarding of models can be opened again.

Comment: I feel the platform will first need to be extended with additional defenses and protections against misuse before the open-to-the-world site will allow on-boarding of arbitrary executable content. Anyhow if this answer was helpful will you please accept it?

Comment: Yeah, this is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I hope the SO people don't mind me explaining how to use SO in a comment here: please note you can upvote an answer (which you have done, thank you) or as the original questioner you can accept the answer by clicking the checkbox. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers