# Onboarding Models in acumos

Tags: linux, artificial-intelligence, foundation, acumos

I have trained a ML model and wanted to onboard this saved model to Acumos marketplace, but I am unable to find the right path to onboard the model to Acumos market place. Kindly guide me as to how to onboard the models to Acumos.

Regards,
Sandeep.

Answer (score 0):

The public site https://marketplace.acumos.org is not open for on-boarding of models.  Please install a local instance of Acumos using the All-In-One (AIO) installer so members of your organization can start using all the features.

This question is a repeat of [Can I publish my model to Acumos marketplace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53069835/can-i-publish-my-model-to-acumos-marketplace)